# change/writing single value to csv file python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

There is an error in my code :

```
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

which i believe is because i am trying to write only one value not a list etc.

```
 exRtFile = open ('exchangeRate.csv')
    exchReader = csv.reader(exRtFile)
    exchWriter = csv.writer(exRtFile)
    loop2=0
    while loop2==0:
        selected=int(input("Please select an option: "))
        if selected == 1:
            change = input("What rate would you like to change: ")
            changeRt = float(input("What would you like to change the rate to: "))
            for row in exchReader:
                currency = row[0]
                if currency == change:
                    crntRt = row[1]
                    crntRt = changeRt
                    exchWriter.writerow(crntRt)
                    exRtFile.close()
```

what would be the best way to fix this, or is there a better wayy to change a value in an CSV file?

csv file:

```
Pound Sterling,1
Euro,1.22
US Dollar,1.67
Japanese Yen,169.948
```

Comment: I haven't tested this (that's why it's a comment) but I'm pretty sure you're right. You may want to change the whole `row` something like `row[1]=changeRt` and then write the hole `row` with the corrected value.

Comment: the problem i c with that is that each row has a different value like this:

Comment: Pound Sterling 1
Euro 1.22
US Dollar 1.67
Japanese Yen 169.948

Comment: could you add a few of the initial lines of the `exchangeRate.csv` file to the question?

Comment: just done, that is the whole file

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code, not tested, that will do what you want.  The idea is to read the text into memory, apply the updates, then write out the results over the original file.

You can further enhance this ask the user if they want to save their changes, and to add new currencies instead of just telling the user they're not known.

In the real world, I would break this code into three separate functions (or even classes), one for reading, one for writing, and one for editing the list.

```
import csv

rates = {}

# read file into dictionary
with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as in_file:
     rdr = csv.reader(in_file)
     for item in reader:
          rates[row[0]] = row[1]

# ask user for updates and apply to dictionary
while true:
     cmd = raw_input('Enter exchange rate to adjust, or blank to exit')
     if cmd is None or cmd.strip() == '':
        break
     if rates.has_key(cmd):
        new_rate = float(raw_input('Enter new exchange rate:'))
        rates[cmd] = new_rate
     else:
        print 'Currency {} is not known.'.format(cmd)

# Write the updated dictionary back over the same file.
with open('csv_file.csv', 'w') as out_file:
     wrtr = csv_writer(out_file)
     wrtr.writerows(rates)
```

Comment: why would u split it into 3 functions, what would be the advantage?

Comment: There are three distinct units of functionality in this program, a reader, a writer, and the main code.  But, written in a single function like this, I don't have the opportunity to name the functional units.  Putting them in functions would allow me (and force me) to do so.  Also, in a real world example, there would likely be considerably more logic in the reader (at least) -- error checking, Exception classes, etc -- and I would want that isolated in a separate RateReader() class.

Comment: this does not work, i got an output like this J,a,p,a,n,e,s,e, ,Y,e,n

U,S, ,D,o,l,l,a,r

P,o,u,n,d, ,S,t,e,r,l,i,n,g

E,u,r,o

Comment: Try `wrtr.writerows(rates.items())` on the last line.  Looks like you're just writing the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question: Yes, the problem is that you were trying to write only a value, while `writerow` expects a list.

That said... Would you consider changing a bit the way your code works?

Here's what I've done (I've tested it now, so I know it works):

- First, ask the user for all the changes to make and keep them in a `dict` where keys are the currency names (*Euro*, for instance) and the value is the new currency value (*5.0*, for instance) The user can get out of the loop pressing `0`
- Second, open and read your `exchangeRate.csv` file row by row. If the `row[0]` (name of the currency) is among the values to change, then change it in that row.
- No matter what happens (regardless of whether the row needed to be changed or not) write that row in a new temporary file `exchangeRate.csv.tmp`
- When all the rows in the original file are read, you'll have `exchangeRate.csv.tmp` with some rows unchanged and some rows changed. Swap (move) the `.tmp` file to `exchangeRate.csv`

Dunno... might be too much change maybe? Here it is, anyway:

```
import csv
import shutil

change_rates = {}
selected = 1
while selected:
    selected=int(raw_input("Please select an option: (1 to change, 0 to exit)"))
    if selected == 1:
        change = raw_input("What rate would you like to change?: ")
        changeRt = float(raw_input("What would you like to change the rate to: "))
        change_rates[change] =  changeRt

if len(change_rates) > 0:
    with open('exchangeRate.csv', 'r') as f_in,\
        open('exchangeRate.csv.tmp', 'w') as f_out:
        exchReader = csv.reader(f_in)
        exchWriter = csv.writer(f_out)
        for row in exchReader:
            if row[0] in change_rates:
                row[1] = change_rates[row[0]]
            exchWriter.writerow(row)
    shutil.move('exchangeRate.csv.tmp', 'exchangeRate.csv')
```

And a sample execution below:

```
Please select an option: (1 to change, 0 to exit)1
What rate would you like to change?: Euro
What would you like to change the rate to: 5
Please select an option: (1 to change, 0 to exit)0

borrajax@borrajax:~/Documents/Tests$ cat ./exchangeRate.csv 
Pound Sterling,1
Euro,5.0
US Dollar,1.67
Japanese Yen,169.948
```

You can always make more optimizations, such as... allow case insensitive searches, or check that the currency has actually been changed (like even if the user says he wants to change the currency *Euro* to *5.0*, if that was the Euro's exchange rate then don't do anything)... Things like that.

**EDIT 1**:

I've just seen Larry Lustig's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22968322/289011) and I agree that for small files as it seems to be your case (files that you can fully load in memory) the continuous reading and writing from disk I posted is not optimal. His idea of keeping everything in memory and then do a bulk write to the same `exchangeRate.csv` file probably is a better fit for your needs.

**EDIT 2**:

To answer your questions in a comment to this answer:

- what does .tmp do at the end of: exchangeRate.csv.tmp:

  It's just a new name. I add the suffix `.tmp` to avoid a naming conflict with your original file (exchangeRate.csv). You could name it whatever you want, though (even `foobar.baz`)
- What is the purpose of 'change' in the variable: change_rates[change] = changeRt:

  `change` is a variable that contains the name of the currency to change (in the usage example I posted, `change` contains the string `"Euro"`, because that's what the user (erm... me) typed on the console. Is just a way of accessing a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict).
- What is the prupose of '[row[0]]' in: row1=change_rates[row[0]].

  We agreed that when reading the file, `row[0]` (just like that, not `[row[0]]`) contains the name of the currency in the file (*Euro, Pound Sterling...* etcetera) right? So at a certain point of the execution `row[0]` will contain the string `"Euro"`, which (in my test example) is the currency the user wanted to change. That string (`"Euro"`) is also a key in the `change_rates` dictionary (because the user said he wanted to change it) so you are querying the **value** for the item with **key** `"Euro"` in the `change_rates` dictionary (which will give you `5.0`). Is pretty much doing `change_rates["Euro"]` To see it a bit more clearer add the line `print "Currencies to change: %s" % change_rates` on the line right above `if len(change_rates) > 0:` (that'll show you how the dictionary looks like)
- what does shutil.move('exchangeRate.csv.tmp', 'exchangeRate.csv') do?

  It copies the file with the new currencies to `exchangeRate.csv` (see the [shutil documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy))

Comment: looks great, just what i was looking for. Just have a few queries. what does .tmp do at the end of: exchangeRate.csv.tmp. What is the purpose of 'change'  in the variable: change_rates[change] =  changeRt. What is the prupose of '[row[0]]' in: row[1]=change_rates[row[0]]. And what does shutil.move('exchangeRate.csv.tmp', 'exchangeRate.csv') do?

Comment: Dangit... I forgot to answer your questions... See my latest-latest edit!! :D :D